# Moonlight stalker and wind stance interaction

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Does the pathfinder feat [Moonlight Stalker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/moonlight-stalker-combat)

> While you have concealment from an opponent,
>    you gain a +2 bonus on attack and damage rolls against that opponent.

interact with the pathfinder feat [Wind Stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/wind-stance-combat---final)?

> If you move more than 5 feet this turn, you gain 20% concealment for 1 round against ranged attacks.

Its unclear whether the partial concealment granted by MS against ranged attacks counts for the purposes of wind stance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does - why would it not? You might want to be more specific about what part of this makes you think it wouldn't apply.

The rules are usually pretty legalistic, so if something gives condition or keyword X, then it's "for reals" for other purposes that use condition or keyword X.

Of course since the concealment from Wind Stance specifies ranged attacks, you only get the bonus against ranged attackers - but Moonlight Stalker does not specify melee attacks, so you could have a lovely run-and-gun archery battle where you have concealment and are getting the hit/damage bonuses. Good trick for a Gunslinger, I'll have to try it.

Concealment is different from "total concealment," which is 50% miss chance instead of 20%, but that's not what Moonlight Stalker says it requires, it just requires normal (20%) concealment.

Comment: Your argument is that I only would get the bonus against ranged attackers. The problem is that seems kind of strange, because whether someone is a rnaged attacker or a melee attacker isn't determined until they actually attack you.
Lets say I spend my turn moving toward someone and attacking them. If they happen to have a bandolier of throwing knives, what makes them a ranged attacker. The fact that they threw a knife last turn? The fact that they throw a knife next turn? The fact that they have the knives at all? The problem is that whether windstance gives concealment is determined when

Comment: the attack happens, but you can trigger moonlight stalker before that.
The concept of a "ranged attacker" doesn't exist in the rules as far as I can tell. Its just an attacker making a ranged attack

Comment: I guess this makes sense if you just define "ranged attacker" as anyone who isn't close enough to make a melee attack against you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

20% appears to be the default miss chance for "concealment," when no other number is stated. Given that, I'd be tempted to argue that the "20%" listing in Wind Stance shouldn't be there: it was just a porting oversight, and it should just be "concealment" with a 20% chance being assumed as the default.

If you do this, the wording becomes clear. Wind Stance grants "concealment," and Moonlight Stalker works with "concealment," so they work together just fine.